# Is decryption in the Browser or on the Server better?

Tags: encryption

I am wondering if it is better to send encrypted data to the browser from the database and have javascript decrypt the data or send a password to a php file (that verifies it with a salt and hash) that sends the unencrypted data to the browser? I am forcing https on this so communications will be encrypted.  I feel like using javascript is better, then it is local and can't be sniffed, though this is mitigated some with https?  Is there any standard for this?

Comment: This seems to be asking for a personal recommendation more than a security best practice. Consider re-phrasing maybe?

Comment: do users trust you?

Comment: It really comes down to what you are trying to protect, and what you are protecting that against.  If you have good TLS then you can already write off sniffing, that isn't an issue.  The vulnerable edge is the web server.  Do you trust the security of the web server? If so, then you've already encrypted the data with TLS up to that point, you're good. If you don't (the server may be compromised, or is placed where that'd be easy) then you can encrypted you application data/payload at the web browser and have the server pass the encrypted data to the back-end (secure) logic server for decrypt.

Comment: @Ruscal Thanks for the reply, that helps a lot.  First time trying to figure all this stuff out and trying to make things secure.  I appreciate the help a lot!

Comment: @SomeGuy thanks for the recommendation on rephrasing the question. :)